# How to avoid uppercase function name while using Function?

Tags: algorithms, capitalization

In LaTeX, I want to define a function in my algorithm, following is my code in case:

```
\begin{algorithm}[h]
   \begin{algorithmic}[1]
       \Function{BuildPolicySet}{PolicySet PS, CCR ccr}
            blabla..
       \EndFunction
   \end{algorithmc}
\end{algorithm}[h]
```

In the pdf I got

> **function** BUILDPOLICYSET(PolicySet PS, CCR ccr)

Actually I don't need the function name being in uppercase.

What should I do if I want the function name in the pdf to be the same as in the LaTeX code?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function name is set using a predefined `\textproc`, which is similar to `\textsc`, changing the shape to small-caps. Redefine this to be empty and things will turn back to normal:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\algrenewcommand\textproc{}% Used to be \textsc

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \show\Function
  \Function{BuildPolicySet}{PolicySet PS, CCR ccr}
    \State blabla..
  \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```